# How can I check if I need to execute `nodetool upgradesstables` on a node?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-enterprise

How can I check if I need to execute `nodetool upgradesstables` on a node? Or will it only do anything if necessary (and simply ignore the command)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `nodetool upgradesstables` after updating Cassandra to a version that needs have your sstables converted to the latest format. Usually this only happens on new major releases. But you should make sure to read the upgrade instructions from the NEXT.txt (e.g. [2.1.8](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-2.1.8/NEWS.txt)) to find out exactly if this step is required.